# Disable visual flow Next button based on default picklist selection like "Choose One"/"Select One"?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, picklist

I'm working on a public New Member application Flow that will be exposed on our website, no authentication required. The Flow is in a Visualforce page that I've updated from Classic to Lightning UX. The object this Flow is tied to is custom.

I am having an issue with picklists: all of ours have "Choose One" as the top/default value. The field is required but there's nothing to stop people from leaving the picklist selection as Choose One instead of making an actual selection.

Is it possible to conditionally disable the Flow's NEXT button or prevent the Flow from moving on until a different selection other than "Choose One" is made in those picklists? Would this require custom JS and/or Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating the API version of my flow.

Apparently it was 6 versions out of date (I was working on a legacy project) and the function I was looking for was introduced somewhere between v49-55. No button disabling is necessary as making the question required and leaving the picklist default value blank will achieve what I was initially looking for.